# How to compute position by FFT?

Tags: fft, frequency-spectrum, dsp-core, position

I have FFT data of x, y, z - axis, Now I'm trying to find the position through FFT data.

**Step 1 :**
For that, applied corresponds to an ordinary frequency i.e rad·s−1,

```
ν = 1/(2*π*f[i])
```

**f** shows real frequency by index upto N/2

**Step 2 :** Applied power factor 2 over ordinary frequency

```
p = (v*v) i.e v2
```

**Step 3 :** Multiplying **p** with ***fx*** & **fy**  resp.

But unable to get the position to draw Lissajous Figure Or complex harmonic motion.

*Thanks in advance! I appreciate If someone pointing out my mistake or any provide me some idea.*

Comment: it is not clear what is the data you are holding on. is it a spectrum' power spectrum? something else?

Comment: Obviously, It's frequency spectrum data of x,y&z

Comment: It's hard to help if all we have is "unable to get the position" since this is a problem we cannot reproduce. Could you share some example data?

Comment: @Florian, Its ok